# Table of Content Takes Pictures as Entries

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am using Word 2013 and I have created a document which contains Headings Level 1 and pictures (no text).
I wanted to enter Table of Content at the beginning of document but when I do that the table of content streaches over 50 photos. These photos are recognized as entries in TOC.

How can I only have one page for ToC which will contain only Level 1 Headings?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some of the pictures where marked as Heading Level 1. 
When I changed that to normal, then I got the ToC on one page without any photos as entries.